# ExpressJS/ReactJS persistent destructuring problem

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using ReactJS, ExpressJS, NodeJS, PostgreSQL, with Redux

I'm attempting to retrieve one row of a SQL table from my backend via an axios call. The call returns the requested data in an object nested in an array `[{..}]`. 
The problem occurs when I attempt to destructure the data or access it via bracket notation.

If I use this notation `this.props.returnedData[0]` to access the one and only object in the returned array I get errors that the returnedData[0] doesn't exist or is undefined.

keep in mind, I can see that it has in fact returned the data in the array via a console.log.

I believe this is due to the componentDidMount returning the data after React has already attempted to render the returnedData[0].

So, questions.
Is there a way to destructure or access that data any other way? 
Is there a "better" way (regarding timing) to retrieve data than using componentDidMount?

Comment: `console.log` is synchronized. You might want to use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSION.stringify(this.props.returnedData)))` and see the issue. Widely speaking, throwing an `IF` somewhere in the code would solve the problem

Comment: yes, element is rendered before props have data so you are getting this error. check [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461706/how-do-i-render-a-component-when-the-data-is-ready) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911012/rendering-react-component-after-api-response) to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse the lengthy explanation, but it shows all steps...

Let's walk through this example: A user goes to a `Dashboard` view...

**client/src/containers/dashboard.js** (this `HOC` container basically just passes Redux actions and state to a `DashboardPanels` component.)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getDashboardData } from '../actions/dashboardActions';
import DashboardPanels from '../components/dashboard/DashboardPanels';

export default connect(state => ({ dashboardData: state.dashboard.data }), { getDashboardData })(props => <DashboardPanels {...props} />)
```

**client/src/components/dashboard/DashboardPanels** (the `DashboardPanels` component is mounted and then executes the passed down Redux `getDashboardData()` action in its `componentDidMount` lifecycle method -- NOTICE: If data hasn't populated yet, it shows a spinner!)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row } from 'antd';

import PageContainer from '../app/panels/pageContainer';
import MessagesPanel from './messagesPanel';
import PlansPanel from './plansPanel';
import PromotionalsPanel from './promotionalsPanel';
import Spinner from '../app/loaders/Spinner';
import SubcribersPanel from './subscribersPanel';
import TemplatesPanel from './templatesPanel';
import TransactionsPanel from './transactionsPanel';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {     
    componentDidMount = () => this.props.getDashboardData();

    render = () => (
        !this.props.dashboardData
            ? <Spinner />
            : <PageContainer>
                <Row style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                    <SubcribersPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                    <PlansPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                    <PromotionalsPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                    <TransactionsPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                    <MessagesPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                    <TemplatesPanel {...this.props.dashboardData} />
                </Row>
              </PageContainer>
    )
}
```

**client/src/actions/dashboardActions.js** (this makes an AJAX request to the `express` API server)

```
import { app } from './axiosConfig';
import * as types from './types';

const getDashboardData = () => dispatch => (
    app.get(`dashboard`)
    .then(({data}) => dispatch({ type: types.SET_DASHBOARD_DATA, payload: data }))
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: types.SERVER_ERROR, payload: err }))
)

export {
  getDashboardData
}
```

**routes/dashboard.js** (front-end AJAX request hits the `express` API server's dashboard route -- passes through authentication, then gets sent to the `getAll` controller)

```
    const { getAll } = require('../controllers/dashboard);
    const { requireRelogin, requireAuth } = require('../services/strategies');

    app.get('/api/dashboard', requireAuth, getAll);
}
```

**controllers/dashboard.js** (The `getAll` controller receives the request, queries the PostgresSQL DB and returns `JSON` or what you referred to as a nested object in an array `[{...}]`. NOTICE that I'm using `res.send()` with the `...spread` operator!)

```
const { db, query: { getAllDashboardDetails }} = require('../database);
const { beginofMonth, endofMonth, parseStringToNum, sendError } = require('../shared/helpers');

        // GETS ALL DASHBOARD DATA
    exports.getAll = async (req, res, done) => {
            const beginMonth = beginofMonth();
            const endMonth = endofMonth();

            try {
                const dashboard = await db.many(getAllDashboardDetails, [req.session.id, beginMonth, endMonth])

                return res.status(201).send(...dashboard);
            } catch (err) { return sendError(err, res, done); }
        }
```

dashboard `JSON` is structured like so on the back-end:

```
dashboard [{
    subscribers: '146',
    inactivesubscribers: '12',
    plans: '12',
    popularplans: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    promotionals: '12',
    popularpromotionals: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    credits: '5',
    creditstotal: '149.95',
    dues: '5',
    duestotal: '149.95',
    charges: '7',
    chargestotal: '209.93',
    refunds: '7',
    refundstotal: '209.93',
    messages: '5',
    activetemplates: '4',
    inactivetemplates: '4' 
}]
```

**client/src/reducers/index.js** (however, because we used `res.send()` with the `...spread` operator, it now becomes a simple object by the time it is saved to Redux's `state` via the `dashboardReducer`)

```
import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const dashboardReducer = (state = {}, { payload, type }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case types.SET_DASHBOARD_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: payload
            };
        default: return state;
    }
}

export default = combineReducers({
    dashboard: dashboardReducer,
    routing
});
```

Redux's `dashboard` state is now structured like so:

```
dashboard: {
    data: {
       subscribers: '146',
       inactivesubscribers: '12',
       plans: '12',
       popularplans: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
       promotionals: '12',
       popularpromotionals: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
       credits: '5',
       creditstotal: '149.95',
       dues: '5',
       duestotal: '149.95',
       charges: '7',
       chargestotal: '209.93',
       refunds: '7',
       refundstotal: '209.93',
       messages: '5',
       activetemplates: '4',
       inactivetemplates: '4'
    } 
 }
```

Since the `DashboardPanels` is connected to Redux via a `HOC` component, we can now access Redux's `state.dashboard.data` via `this.props.dashboardData`.

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you are trying to access an array index that does not exist, because your data has not arrived yet. 
One way to resolve this issue may be to do a quick check if the array has got an index before accessing it. Something like this:

```
const data = this.props.returnedData.length > 0 ? this.props.returnedData[0]: {}
```

And then you use the new "data" variable further on, for example in the rendering method or similar.